# Windows 10 - 2 IPs on one NIC - Internet connectivity issues

Tags: networking, windows-10, ip, network-adapter

We have a Windows 10 PC with one NIC connected to a switch. On the other end we have 2 routers, one 192.168.2.X (connected to the internet) the other 10.73.19.X (not connected to the internet). Both subnet mask 255.255.255.0. The idea is that we have machines that we want to give internet connectivity and others we don't (thermal printers & tablets).

The PC needs to be connected to both networks.

We set the IP properties of the PC to be:

IP: 10.73.19.100 Subnet: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 10.73.19.1

We then added another IP under Advanced to be: IP: 192.168.2.100 Subnet: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.2.1

We have no connectivity issues on the first network. But the PC keeps losing and getting back internet connectivity on the second. I don't understand why.

Another thing I noticed is that if I connect a USB modem to the PC, I only get internet connectivity if I disable the LAN network adaptor.

My question is: What could be causing the network disruptions on 192.168.2.X network? And why is the PC not routing internet thru the USB modem unless the network adaptor is disabled?

Thank you

Comment: Is there another device somewhere with `192.168.2.100`?

Comment: No there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to have two gateways setup in this situation

Do you access any other network from the `10.73.19.x` Network?
If not remove the gateway of `10.73.19.1` as this makes it think it can access other networks from this one (whereas it doesn't seem it can from your post)

You only need a gateway on a network where you need to then get to another IP not in the same subnet.